# How can we decide whether a token is JWT or not by inspecting the token?

Tags: c++, authentication, oauth, jwt, access-token

I am in a middle of a project that uses access token identification and validation. We are trying to decide the type of the access token (basically JWT or non-JWT) after inspecting the access token. I am not sure if I can identify a JWT by identifying 3 parts separated by "."  since someone can make a non-JWT with their preferred characters which may include ".". It is really thankful, if someone can help me with something.

Comment: You can try parsing the token using a jwt library, if parsing fails, it's not JWT.

Comment: @bereal
thanks it works, But I heard that using exceptions to identify it, is not a standard way.(Since it will throw an exception if fails).

Comment: That's quite an idiomatic way of checking stuff in Python: you try it and if it raises an exception, you handle it. It's called [_Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission_](https://docs.python.org/3.7/glossary.html#term-eafp).

Comment: Okay, in that case, we need to aware of all the  exceptions if we use a library, don't we? I re- searched on this. Looks like there is a debate on this. However people say it can be used with python(mostly). In my case I am using c++.

Comment: Ah sorry, for some reason I thought it's Python. I'll tag the language then.

Comment: But you will have to verify the token at some point anyway, right? Why not immediately?

Comment: Yeah it is about implementing api gateway. Plan is to go for introseption end point it it is not a JWT. So that's why I am trying to get something on identifying the type.

Comment: Well, if it consists of three dot-separated parts, and each is a valid base64 string, and first two are valid JSON objects after decoding, then it's relatively safe to assume it's JWT. But, again, doing all those checks is essentially parsing.

Comment: Yeah, That makes sense

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.